# Can I null an object with its own extension method?

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I wrote extension method to Timer class to destroy it after certain amount of time. seems like it actually only set false in timer.enable fields but don't really set the whole things to false. Is there a way to nullify an object from it own extension method?

and another thing - is it good practice to implement it in that way or I should expect sync issues and more surprises?

timer.DestroyAfter(1.Hours()) :

```
     public static void DestroyAfter(this Timer timer, TimeSpan timeSpan)
      {
        var killingTimer = new Timer(timeSpan.TotalMilliseconds)
            {
                AutoReset = false,
            };

        killingTimer.Elapsed += (sender, e) =>
            {
                timer.Stop();
                **timer = null;** //doesn't seem to work though line is executed
                killingTimer.Stop();
                killingTimer = null;
            };
        killingTimer.Start();
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would only be possible if the "this" parameter was also a ref parameter, which it is not.

So the answer is no (in the current C# implementation)

Regarding your other question: there's nothing wrong with the way you implemented it (stopping the timer and clearing the reference to the captured "killingTimer" variable).

Comment: Thanks.follow up question - since no one really points to the killingTimer (its lifetime is only within this function) - is it possible that the GC will kill it before the timer is able to perform its action? I mean - is there explanation that will guruntee that the killingTimer will perform its action?

Comment: Th GC won't touch killingTimer because it is captured and referenced in a closure for the "Elapsed" event handler.

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing special about extensions methods. What the `this` modifier says it that call like `timer.DestroyAfter(time)` should be compiled as if you wrote `DestroyAfter(timer, time)`.

And in normal methods, change to the parameter variable doesn't affect the original variable. In normal methods, there is a way to achieve that: use `ref` parameter. But you can't do that with the `this` parameter of an extension method.

Besides, this would be very confusing: If I write `timer.DestroyAfter(time)`, then suddenly some time in the future, `timer` becomes `null`? I certainly would not expect that.